# Right span positioning (high resolution)

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would like for this element:

```
<span class="less_options">Weniger Auswahl</span>
```

to be *next* to the button and not under it.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bcnq2Lk/

HTML code:

```
<div id="search_job_simple" class="form_padding">
<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Jobsuche eingrentzen:
        <span>Wählen Sie eine "Jobart" und einen "Stadtteil", oder erweitern Sie ihre Suche unter "Mehr Auswahl".</span>
    </legend>
    <label for="j_select">
        <span>Jobart:</span>
        <select name="j_select" size="1">
            <option>Gelegenheitsjob</option>
            <option>Ausbildungsplatz</option>
            <option>Praktika</option>
            <option>Fachkräfte</option>
            <option>Freiemitarbeiter/Freelancer</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="j_destrict">
        <span>Stadtteil:</span>
        <select name="j_destrict" size="1">
            <option>Charlottenburg</option>
            <option>Friedrichshain</option>
            <option>Hellersdorf</option>
            <option>Hohenschönhausen</option>
            <option>Köpenick</option>
            <option>Kreuzberg</option>
            <option>Lichtenberg</option>
            <option>Marzahn</option>
            <option>Mitte</option>
            <option>Neuköln</option>
            <option>Pankow</option>
            <option>Prenzlauer Berg</option>
            <option>Reinickendorf</option>
            <option>Schöneberg</option>
            <option>Spandau</option>
            <option>Steglitz</option>
            <option>Tempelhof</option>
            <option>Tiergarten</option>
            <option>Treptow</option>
            <option>Wedding</option>
            <option>Weißensee</option>
            <option>Wilmersdorf</option>
            <option>Zehlendorf</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" name="suche_f_btn" class="submit_button">Los!</button>
    <span class="more_options">Mehr Auswahl</span>
</fieldset>
```

and my CSS code:

```
/***********************************************
            Alles auf Null setzen
***********************************************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 100%;
}


/***********************************************
            Header
***********************************************/

#header {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../pics/bg.png);
}

#logo {
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(../pics/jobber_logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:45px 25px;

}


/***********************************************
            Navigation
***********************************************/

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 50px;
}

/* Links in der Navigation */
nav a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav a:active {
    color: black;
}


/***********************************************
            Content
***********************************************/

#content {
    clear: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Jede zweite Zeile in der Tabelle farbig */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

th {
    background-color: #8dc043;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    font: 18px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

tr {
    /*border: 2px solid #47641c;*/
}

td {
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}

/*sets padding around the table*/
.table_padding {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding: 45px 0 45px 0; 
}


/***********************************************
                Footer
***********************************************/

footer {
    background-color: #696969;
    height: 50px;
}

footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 50px;
}

/* Links in der Navigation */
footer a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

footer a:visited {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

footer a:hover {
     color: white;
}

footer a:active {
    color: white;
}


 /***********************************************
                Classes
***********************************************/

.more_options {
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 40px;
}

.less_options {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 40px;
}


 /***********************************************
                ID's
***********************************************/

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
}

#comments {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding: 45px 0 25px 0;
}

#f_box {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#f_title {
    padding: 20px 45px 0 45px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

#f_title span {
    float: right;
}

#f_comment {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 45px 45px 45px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

#control_center {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#control_center_links {
    padding: 45px;
}


/***********************************************
                Forms
***********************************************/

.form_padding {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

#insert_padding {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding: 45px 0 45px 0;
}

#form_1, #form_2 {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.smart-green {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}

.smart-green fieldset {
    border: none;
}

.smart-green legend {
    font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 25px 15px 15px 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8dc043;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
}

 .smart-green legend>span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.smart-green label {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 40px 5px;
    clear: left;
}

.smart-green label>span {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

 .smart-green input[type="text"], .smart-green input[type="email"], .smart-green textarea, .smart-green select, .smart-green input[type="password"] {
    color: #555;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    background-color: #FBFBFB;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
    font: normal 14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.smart-green textarea{
    height:150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.smart-green select {
    background: url('down-arrow.png') no-repeat right, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #E9E9E9 100%);
    background: url('down-arrow.png') no-repeat right, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FBFBFB), color-stop(100%,#E9E9E9));
    appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}

.smart-green .submit_button {
    clear: left;
    background-color: #8dc043;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inherit;
}

.smart-green .submit_button:hover {
    background-color:#80A24A;
}

.sub_field {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub_field legend {
    font: 18px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
}

.radio_matches {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
}

.radio_destrict {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.radio_destrict li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Sorry, for my poor english!! Hope, that somebody can help me.. :P

Comment: Have you tried removing the margin from the class? Its set as `margin-left: 40px;` which could push it down if there container is not as wide.

Comment: I could be missing it, but I don't see a "less-options" span in your code...

Comment: I can't see less_options in your html. Are you talking about more_options?

Answer (score 1):

In your `submit_button` class you set `display: inherit;` which take the value from his parent which is a fieldset which is `display: block;`

You should remove `display: inherit;` from `submit_button` class.

Comment: You could also change it to `inline` or `inline block` to get the same effect.

Comment: ok, that it will solve my problem, when the form is closed. But when I click on this <span class="less_options">Weniger Auswahl</span> my button is weird on the right side. I hope, you know what I mean? Just click on "Mehr Auswahl".

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your CSS:

```
.submit_button {
    float: left;
}

.submit_button + span {
    line-height: 32px; /* this will vertical-align your text */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `style="display:inline-block;` to the button.  *** EDIT *** both buttons

Obviously you can modify the `margin-left` to pull the text closer.  Also can implement in the CSS by adding `display:inline-block;` to `.smart-green .submit_button`

Also you need to add: `width:100%` to `.radio_destrict` so the button wont pull up on large resolution screens.  Or look into a media query

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bcnq2Lk/6/

Comment: Also the same.. If I click on a high resolution on the <span> "Mehr Auswahl" the button is weird on the right side. I would like to have it on the same position

Comment: Corrected.  Didn't mention the second bottom, fixed.  Simply applying `inline-block` to .smart-green .submit_bottom works as shown in updated JSFiddle.  (I had applied it to the one button not knowing you had two)

Comment: I am in school at the moment, I will try it back home. On my notebook is it working. But at home I got a 27 Zoll Monitor with 2560x1440 resolution and there was the button weird on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your button to make elements' flow be horizontal instead of vertical.

```
.smart-green .submit_button {
    ...    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please include a description of what your answer accomplishes. Code-only answers aren't usually helpful to people who need to ask in the first place.

Comment: Same here.. If I click on a high resolution on the <span> "Mehr Auswahl" the button is weird on the right side. I would like to have it on the same position

Answer (score 0):

just change the display of `.smart-green .submit_button` to `inline` <s>and the `.more_options` too</s>.

like: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/1bcnq2Lk/2/

Comment: `span` by default is `inline`

Comment: @SimplyCraig oh, true :)

Comment: If I click on a high resolution on the <span> "Mehr Auswahl" the button is weird on the right side. I would like to have it on the same position.

Comment: please try to understand your script, and go trough step by stem.. then you understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Span tag is n inline element and button block element.To fix that set your span display to block